# Can my permutations function be defined using iteration?

Tags: function-construction, functional-style

I have two functions, `tuples` and `perm`. They are similar.

```
tuples[L_, 0] := {{}};
tuples[L_, k_] := Join @@ Table[{x}~Join~y, {x, L}, {y, tuples[L, k - 1]}];

perm[L_, 0] := {{}};
perm[L_, k_] := Join @@ Table[{x}~Join~y, {x, L}, {y, perm[Select[L, # != x &], k - 1]}];

(*tuples[{1, 2, 3}, 2]*)
(*{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}}*)
(*perm[{1, 2, 3}, 2]*)
(*{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}}*)
```

I know `tuples` can be defined using `Nest`, but I don't know whether `perm` can be defined using `Nest` or `Fold`.

```
tuples2[L_, k_] := Nest[Join @@ Table[x~Join~{y}, {x, #}, {y, L}] &, {{}}, k];
```

Comment: Could you please tell us what `perm` is supposed to do?  Is it working correctly or not?  And what specifically is your question?

Comment: @whuber `perm` is equivalent to `Permutations`. It looks like it is a question of how to implement it functionally.

Comment: By comparing to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Permutations.html), it is clear that the implementation given in the question is *not* equivalent to `Permutations`.  For instance, the present implementation would not reproduce the behavior of `Permutations` with just one argument or with a list as a second argument. I think it's incumbent on the OP to tell us more precisely what he wants, rather than hoping our guesses will be correct.

Comment: Have you looked at [Gray codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graycode)?

Comment: @whuber You are correct in that it doesn't fully implement `Permutations`, but it is intended to mimic the behavior of the third form, as can be seen by the results of `Permutations[{1, 2, 3}, {2}]`.

Comment: @rc Yes, one would *guess* that...  Another point: exactly how much of that behavior should be reproduced?  For instance, the sequence of elements in the output list does not appear to be documented, so would it be okay for `perm` to produce the same output as `Permutation` but in a different order?  *We don't know* because the OP has not specified what the desired behavior is.

Comment: @whuber actually, it is not a guess, the OP commented that that interpretation is correct. But, I'm having trouble seeing how the other details are relevant. Why is some ambiguity not allowed?

Comment: @whuber and @rcollyer: I think the OP's question can be boiled down to this: "Assuming `perm` is correct and does what the OP wants it to do (regardless of similarity to `Permutation`), can it be written using `Nest` or `Fold`?".

Comment: @rm-rf ah, more succinctly put.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An iterative procedure could look as follows: when you call your `perm` function and when `k>0`, then a first step would be, to build your result for `k==1`. This is all elements of the list wrapped in `List`

```
Permutations[{1,2,3},{1}]
 (* Out[36]= {{1},{2},{3}} *)
```

With this start, you could concentrate to think about how a function would take e.g. `{1}` and create all *children*. This process is done in the recursion of your original function. Nevertheless, it's not hard to calculate this without recursion. The `{1}` would be transformed into a list `{{1,2},{1,3}}`, meaning you append to the initial list `{1}` all members of your `all` list which are not contained in the initial `{1}`.

When you want to do this for `{{1},{2},{3}}`, you can `Map` the same function over the list. Since this would leave you with 3 sublists, you need to join them. This basic idea can be put into a function `step`, which is called after we initialized our `result`

```
step[partialRes_, all_] := 
 Join @@ Map[Table[Append[#, new], {new, Complement[all, #]}] &, partialRes];

permHalirutan[l_, k_Integer] := Module[{res, iter = k - 1},
  res = Partition[l, 1];
  Nest[step[#, l] &, res, iter]
]
```

That should do an equivalent work as your original function.

**And before someone asks**, yes, there is of course a more compact form of the same method kicking some of the unnecessary characters which make it more readable, but less nerdy:

```
p[l_,k_]:=Nest[Join@@(Table[Append[#,n],{n,Complement[l,#]}]&/@#)&,List/@l,k-1]
```